# Java exit while loop from called method

Tags: java

How do I make this code exit after the s variable updates to 0? As of now, its executing the whole block outputting the last print statement before stopping. Is this the normal behaviour of while loop?

```
public class test {

    private static int i = 0;
    private static int s = 1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        s:
        while(s>0 && i==0) {
            s();
        }


    }
    public static void s() {
        System.out.println(s);
        s--;
        //I want the program to stop here since s is already 0.
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Comment: Place a break in loop

Comment: yes this is normal behavior of the while loop. Since you have a function in your loop it will fully execute the function and anything else in the loop before it goes back to the start of the loop and checks the parameters for looping

Comment: The loop doesn't instantly die when its condition becomes false; it tests the condition every time it encounters the loop and then stops when it finds that it is false. And don't use labels (`s:`) in Java; they're a language feature, but stay away in real code.

Comment: You can use return; by adding if (s==0) condition in void s() . This is also another way.

Comment: @HKG Thanks, I used your solution and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void s() {
            System.out.println(s);
            s--;
            if(s!=0)
            {
                //I want the program to stop here since s is already 0.
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, this works too. Is there a significant difference between this and @HKG 's solution using return?